# tablesorter nested table th width

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablesorter

HTML:

```
<div class="container">  
<table class="tablesorter">  
    <thead><th></th></thead>  
    <tbody>  
        <tr><td><table>  
              <thead><tr>  
                  <th>some content that should inherit its parent tag's width</th>  
              </tr></thead>  
        </table></td></tr>  
    </tbody>  
</table>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tablesorter th { width: 20%; }  
.tablesorter table th { width: 100%; }  //won't work  
.tablesorter table th { width: 1080px } //works! for some absolute value
```

My css works fine with the outer table, as evidenced by the width per cell on my output. but when the `<th>` is inside another `<table>`, width is dependent on the content of said `tag` so I just placed some high number value as width... like `width: 1080px` and the INNER `<th>` works (occupies the whole OUTER `<td>` its contained in.

But isn't this semantically incorrect if I just stick with the 1080px or w/e solution? What am I missing here? I've searched thru chrome's dev console for hours and no avail.

display: block for the said `<th>` also won't seem to work.

Comment: `<table>some content that should inherit its parent tag's width</table>` is not valid HTML

Comment: @Mottie sorry, was meant to say `...` implying correct HTML. edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the nested table "adjusts" itself to match the width of its content. So if you set the nested table width to `100%`, it should work as expected ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1578/))

```
.tablesorter th {
  width: 20%;
}

.tablesorter table,
.tablesorter table th {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: SWEET! i missed the `.tablesorter table` property big time. I was aware of the adjust behavior and assumed its width being set to 100% as inherited from its `<td>` container. why won't `.tablesorter table` assume the 100% width? I was looking at dev console and I'm pretty sure everything was set at 100%...

Comment: I have no idea LOL.. that's just how the browser behaves.